# Refer to own type for a template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Here's the simplest case of what I'm trying to do:

```
template <template <typename...> class Wrapper>
struct WrapperTraits { };

template <typename... Whatever>
struct Foo {
private:
    // I want Foo here to refer to the template, and not the current
    // concrete type (which is injected into the namespace by default)
    using Traits = WrapperTraits<Foo>;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the error on clang 3.6 (it compiles fine on gcc 4.8 and 5.2):

```
error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
using Traits = WrapperTraits<Foo>;
^
1 error generated.
Compilation failed
```

Here is the example in question on godbolt: https://goo.gl/cSx6QR

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `template<class...Ts>using Foo_Z=Foo<Ts...>;` then use `Foo_Z`?

Comment: cannot reproduce the error : https://ideone.com/rXiUhl

Comment: @tobi303 That's on gcc 5.1. It fails to compile on clang. I provided a link on godbolt

Comment: sorry I missed the "works fine on..." point

Comment: Known clang bug. Another workaround is writing `Foo::template Foo`.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, figured it out. Need to scope it to the namespace it's in:

```
template <template <typename...> class Wrapper>
struct WrapperTraits { };


template <typename... Whatever>
struct Foo {
private:
    using Traits = WrapperTraits<::Foo>; // explicit namespace
};


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```